# Simple query Optimization?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

```
SELECT /*+ index (c EMP_JPB_IDX) */ a.emp, a.mgr, c.job, b.dname
FROM   emp c,
       emp_mgr a,
       dept d,
       emp d
WHERE c.deptno = b.deptno AND
      a.empno = c.empno AND
      d.empno = a.mgrno AND
      d.job = 'ANALYST';
```

How can I optimize this query?
And what the `/*+ index (c EMP_JPB_IDX) */` means?

Comment: You can't.  You have the same table alias for two different tables, so the query is not properly written.  Another good idea would be to write the query using proper ANSI `join` syntax.

Comment: First what RDBMS are you using, Second use ANSI JOIN. Third publish the query plan

Answer (score 2):

`/*+ index (c EMP_JPB_IDX) */` is Oracle's syntax for sending hints to the optimizer.
It means that the optimizer should attempt to use the `EMP_JPB_IDX` when filtering the `c` (i.e., `emp`) table.

Note that hints are just as their namesake suggests - just hints. They do not **force** the optimizer to use this index, and it's more often than not a dodgy practice to rely on them.

You can see the full nitty-gritty details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#5156).

Comment: A hint is an order, not just a suggestion- http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/hinting-2/  Oracle can only ignore a hint if there is no valid plan that would obey the hint.  If there is no such index, for example, or if an index access would potentially result in different output (if, for example, Oracle needed to retrieve `NULL` values that would not be in the index.

Answer (score 0):

What was the issue with query right now? is it running for longer than expected? check the explain plan on the query? check if table statistics are up to date? Also check you have all indexes created?  Its /*+ index (c EMP_JPB_IDX) */ oracle hint to query to force query to use index. Learn about it here                                                                                 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm                                      you can also use Parallel hint on query to execute query in parallel(Please read about possible negative impact of Parallel hint, it might drain your CPU usage. So before using it always test the scenario in development/test environments before use anything in production).

Comment: For the god's sake, please do not advice novice users to use `PARALLEL` hint. Don't ever tell them that it exists. You are giving A-bomb to a man who is not familiar with shotgun yet. At least warn them that it [should be used with high precautions](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:39946845137685).